# Straighten tilted line in square of oppositions with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a square of oppositions (an old logical structure) with two lines of text in some of the edges. When I run the code below, the line between "some" and "not every" is tilted in a very annoying way. I am not sure how to fix this.

I have tried adding a line beneath "Every" with `\vspace*{1\baselineskip}` but it doesn't work. Moreover, it would look strange. I have also tried specifying the position of I ("Some") as "left of=O", where O is "not all", but it tilts "some" towards the center.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,calc}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

% based on code in http://www.actual.world/resources/tex/doc/TikZ.pdf

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]

    \node (A) {\begin{tabular}{c} \textbf{Every} \\ \end{tabular}};
    \node (E) [right=of A, xshift=2cm] {\begin{tabular}{c} \textbf{No} \\ every(not(...)) \end{tabular}};
    \node (O) [below=of E] {\begin{tabular}{c}  \textbf{Not every}  \\ not(every(...))\end{tabular}};
    \node (I) [below=of A] {\begin{tabular}{c}  \textbf{Some} \\ not(every(not(...)) \end{tabular}};

    \coordinate (CENTER) at ($(A)!0.5!(O)$);

    \node (contra) at (CENTER) {\begin{tabular}{c}Contradictories\\ \tiny{cannot both be true and cannot both be false} \end{tabular}};
    \path[<->] (A) edge node[] {\begin{tabular}{c}Contraries\\ \tiny{cannot both be true but can both be false} \end{tabular}} (E);
    \path[<->] (I) edge node[] {\begin{tabular}{c}Subcontraries\\ \tiny{cannot both be false but can both be true}\end{tabular}} (O);
    \path[->] (A) edge node[rotate=90] {\begin{tabular}{c}Subalterns\\ \tiny{must be true if superaltern is true}\end{tabular}} (I);
    \path[->] (E) edge node[rotate=-90] {\begin{tabular}{c}Subalterns\\ \tiny{must be true if superaltern is true}\end{tabular}} (O);

    \path[->] (contra) edge (A);
    \path[->] (contra) edge (E);
    \path[->] (contra) edge (I);
    \path[->] (contra) edge (O);

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nodes `A` and `E` doesn't have the same height, then positioning `O` and `I` with `below=of ...` produces a missalignment of lower nodes.

I propose to place `I` with `below=of A` and later on place `O` with `at (I-|E)`, then all nodes will be horizontaly and vertically aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,calc}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

% based on code in http://www.actual.world/resources/tex/doc/TikZ.pdf

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]

    \node (A) {\begin{tabular}{c} \textbf{Every} \\ \end{tabular}};
    \node (E) [right=of A, xshift=2cm] {\begin{tabular}{c} \textbf{No} \\ every(not(...)) \end{tabular}};
    \node (I) [below=of A] {\begin{tabular}{c}  \textbf{Some} \\ not(every(not(...)) \end{tabular}};
    \node (O) at (I-|E) {\begin{tabular}{c}  \textbf{Not every}  \\ not(every(...))\end{tabular}};

    \coordinate (CENTER) at ($(A)!0.5!(O)$);

    \node (contra) at (CENTER) {\begin{tabular}{c}Contradictories\\ \tiny{cannot both be true and cannot both be false} \end{tabular}};
    \path[<->] (A) edge node[] {\begin{tabular}{c}Contraries\\ \tiny{cannot both be true but can both be false} \end{tabular}} (E);
    \path[<->] (I) edge node[] {\begin{tabular}{c}Subcontraries\\ \tiny{cannot both be false but can both be true}\end{tabular}} (O);
    \path[->] (A) edge node[rotate=90] {\begin{tabular}{c}Subalterns\\ \tiny{must be true if superaltern is true}\end{tabular}} (I);
    \path[->] (E) edge node[rotate=-90] {\begin{tabular}{c}Subalterns\\ \tiny{must be true if superaltern is true}\end{tabular}} (O);

    \path[->] (contra) edge (A);
    \path[->] (contra) edge (E);
    \path[->] (contra) edge (I);
    \path[->] (contra) edge (O);

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Changes in comparison to your MWE:

- defined new node distances (and eliminated `xshift` for node `E`)
- for main nodes is defined `minimum height=3em`, consequently horizontal lines are straight
- increase is font size from `\tiny` to `\scriptsize` for more easy resding
- removed `\tabular` environments in nodes, instead it is used option `align=center` for every node
- for arrows is used library `arrows.meta` (matter of personal taste)

Result of above changes is more concise MWE with desired features :-) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% based on code in http://www.actual.world/resources/tex/doc/TikZ.pdf
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    > = {Straight Barb[length=1mm]},
node distance = 5cm and 7cm,
mn/.style = {minimum height=3em}, % mn: main nodes
every node/.style = {align=center},
every edge quotes/.style={auto}
                        ]
\node (A) [mn]              {\textbf{Every}};
\node (E) [mn,right=of A]   {\textbf{No} \\ every(not(...))};
\node (O) [mn,below=of E]   {\textbf{Not every}\\ not(every(...))};
\node (I) [mn,below=of A]   {\textbf{Some}\\ not(every(not(...))};

\coordinate (CENTER) at ($(A)!0.5!(O)$);

\node (contra) [mn] at (CENTER) {Contradictories\\
                            \scriptsize cannot both be true and
                                        cannot both be false};
\draw[<->]  (A) edge node {Contraries\\
                            \scriptsize cannot both be true
                            and cannot both be false}   (E)
            (I) edge node {Subcontraries\\
                            \scriptsize cannot both be false
                            but can both be true}       (O);
\draw[->]   (A) edge node[rotate=90]
                      {Subalterns\\
                       \scriptsize must be true if
                       superaltern is true}             (I)
            (E) edge node[align=center, rotate=-90]
                      {Subalterns\\
                       \scriptsize must be true if
                       superaltern is true}             (O);

\draw[->]   (contra) edge (A)
            (contra) edge (E)
            (contra) edge (I)
            (contra) edge (O);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```